# material-ui slider how can i use activated (css api) to hide the shadows

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

i wang to know to how can i use activated to change the style of thumb and hide the shadows of thumb

here is attribute description of the official website
activated  ---- Class applied to the track and thumb elements to trigger JSS nested styles if activated.

here is my code

```
    const style={
         thumb:{
    bottom:15,
    '&$focused, &:hover':{
    boxShadow: `0px 0px 0px 0px`,
    }, 
  },activated:{
    boxShadow: `0px 0px 0px 0px` 
  },      
}
```

...

```
<Slider
      value={value}
      aria-labelledby="slider-image"  
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      max='10'
      step='1'
      classes={{
        container: classes.slider,
        track:classes.track,
        thumb:classes.thumb,
        focused:classes.focused,
        trackBefore:classes.trackBefore,
        trackAfter:classes.trackAfter,
        activated:classes.activated
      }}
      thumb={
        <Thumb num={value}/>
      }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question: **how can i use activated to change the style of thumb and hide the shadows of thumb?**

- You must create a theme, in this example i'm importing lensIcon, then i apply my theme:

  ```
  import LensIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LensOutlined";
  import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

  const themeIcon = createMuiTheme({
    shadows: Array(25).fill('none')
  })

  <Slider
    value={value}
    aria-labelledby="slider-icon"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    thumb={<LensIcon theme={themeIcon} />}
  />
  ```

Comment: theme={theme}  The report says that the theme is not defined

Comment: And the<thumb /> is my custom component,what should i pay attention to 
when i design <thumb/>  then can  be able to achieve the effect you said.

Comment: I' ve removed attribute theme={theme} from <Slider />